# Create three.js components with map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I've created a react-three-fiber functional component to load a glb file of a butterfly with animation and I am returning a primitive with the scene of the glb passed as an object prop. It is nested in a mesh, that is nested in a scene, that is nested in a group.

```
function Butterfly({ speed, factor, url, ...props }) {
  const { scene, nodes, materials, animations } = useLoader(GLTFLoader, url);
  const group = useRef()
  const [mixer] = useState(() => new THREE.AnimationMixer())
  useEffect(() => mixer.clipAction(animations[0], group.current).play(), [])
   useFrame((state, delta) => {
    group.current.rotation.y -= Math.sin((delta * factor) / 2) * Math.cos((delta * factor) / 2) * 2
    mixer.update(delta * speed)
  })
  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null}>
      <scene name="Scene" {...props}>
        <mesh
        name="Object_0"
        >
          <primitive object={scene}/>
         </mesh>
      </scene>
    </group>
  )
}
```

This component is then returned in separate function in each iteration of an array.

```
function Butterflies() {
  const copyArray = new Array(100).fill()
  console.log(copyArray);
  return copyArray.map((j, i) => {
    const x = (15 + Math.random() * 30) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? -1 : 1)
    const y = -10 + Math.random() * 20
    const z = -5 + Math.random() * 10
    return <Butterfly key={i} position={[x, y, z]} rotation={[0, x > 0 ? Math.PI : 0, 0]}  speed='5' factor='1.5' url='/blue_butterfly.glb' />
  })
}
```

However, this function is only returning one butterfly instead of 100.

[single butterfly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sje4u.png)

I think my issue has something to do with the return in the Butterfly component. I've tried only returning the primitive with props and a ref, but that doesn't render anything. I've tried going through the console.log of the the glb file and found the geometry and tried passing that as a prop to the mesh along with the materials, but that only rendered a white butterfly shape without the animation from the scene. Why is this only returning 1 butterfly instead of 100?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this may be happening because `scene` is the same across all butterfly components, so it's only aded to the last butterfly.

Comment: This helped me solve it. I just had to make a copy of the glb file for each loop. So I just made it loop through an array of 10 and made 10 copies of the glb file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `Butterflies()` is in Butterflies.js and you are trying return many `<Butterfly>` here, however react component can only have one parent.

try this in `Butterflies()`:

```
function Butterflies() {
  const copyArray = new Array(100).fill()
  console.log(copyArray);
  return(
    <>
    {copyArray.map((j, i) => {
    const x = (15 + Math.random() * 30) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? -1 : 1)
    const y = -10 + Math.random() * 20
    const z = -5 + Math.random() * 10
    return <Butterfly key={i} position={[x, y, z]} rotation={[0, x > 0 ? Math.PI : 0, 0]}  speed='5' factor='1.5' url='/blue_butterfly.glb' />
  })}
    </>)}
```

Or store it in a variable first, for the example:

```
function Butterflies() {
  const copyArray = new Array(100).fill()
  console.log(copyArray);
  const items=copyArray.map((j, i) => {
    const x = (15 + Math.random() * 30) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? -1 : 1)
    const y = -10 + Math.random() * 20
    const z = -5 + Math.random() * 10
    return <Butterfly key={i} position={[x, y, z]} rotation={[0, x > 0 ? Math.PI : 0, 0]}  speed='5' factor='1.5' url='/blue_butterfly.glb' />
    })
  return(
    <>
    {items}
    </>
)}
```